# Selectively manipulate a string in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, search

I'm trying to create a program to automate a certain conversion process which is required to add new playermodels to game servers which currently involves lots of repetitive manual work.

However, I'm struggling to get over this one seemingly simple bit! The user selects a file at the start of the process using the file dialog which throws out a string of the directory like this:

"M:\User\Documents\Playermodel Program\Raw Addon\Stalker Playermodel\models\player\zelpa\model.mdl"

I want to shorten this string down to:

"models\player\zelpa\model.mdl"

The issue being, that anything before there could change. So can the file name, and any directory between 'models' and the folder the actual model is in! So the only sure bit to go from is /models/ which will always be there.

What I'd like to do is take the string and delete everything up to a part of the string that equals "\models\" and delete everything up to it, as well as the first "\". It needs to be a search for "\models\" and not "models\" as somebody may have a folder named "playermodels" which would throw it off!

How can I achieve this? For a seemingly simple problem, I fear it may have a very complex solution!

Comment: The string of the directory you are displaying, is that an exception or a result? Also, have you looked into regex?

Comment: The first string is a result, as in, that is an example of a typical input. The second string (what I want to shorten it to) is what I need for use in the program itself!

I'm not sure how regular expressions would be applied here, considering I only have one 'anchor' point which is always the same, regular expressions don't seem the best way to match it, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry, I was think of a different problem. You can just perform `myFilePath.Split('\')` to have a string[] where you can just extract the segments of the file path you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following along correctly, you can just use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the `\models\` part, and [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract the part of the path you are interested in:

```
Dim fileName = "M:\User\Documents\Playermodel Program\Raw Addon\Stalker Playermodel\models\player\zelpa\model.mdl"
Dim partPath = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("\models\") + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because LINQ is so much fun...

```
Dim s As String = "M:\User\Documents\Playermodel Program\Raw Addon\Stalker Playermodel\models\player\zelpa\model.mdl"
Dim returnValue As String = String.Join("\", s.Split("\".ToCharArray()).Reverse().Take(4).Reverse())
```

This splits by "\" and takes the last four parts.  It does this by reversing the list, taking the first four parts, and then reversing it again.  Then it joins them back together using "\".

Comment: I love LINQ too, but I don't think the "first four parts" thing is fixed - there could be more directories in the path after "models".  So, perhaps something like this: `String.Join("\", fileName.Split({"\"c}).SkipWhile(Function(x) x.ToLower() <> "models"))`.

Comment: You are correct, sir! :)  Bad reading of requirements on my part, but I'll leave it up because your solution looks nice!